# how to validate text in custom validate patterns using angular

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-forms

I want to validate text only using this pattern  `~*\|:"<>?/`. Below is my textbox

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] ="newReferenceValue"  #referencevar="ngModel" name="referencevar" (keyup.enter)="save()" pattern='^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:"]*$' style="margin: 8px;width: 60%;">

 <div *ngIf="referencevar.errors?.pattern">
         not valid not partens  
  </div>
```

Comment: have you tried ng forms?

Comment: no i'm try only two way binding .error message is show but i'cant validate only this  ~*\|:"<>?/ text

Comment: I want to create correct Regex  pattern='^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:"]*$'

Comment: Try angular forms or ngforms so it will allow you as a html validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'am using this Regex pattern `^[^~*\\|>:"?</"]*$` work fine

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] ="newReferenceValue"  #referencevar="ngModel" name="referencevar"  maxlength="{{textLengthValue}}" (keyup.enter)="save()" pattern='^[^~*\\|>:"?</"]*$' style="margin: 8px;width: 60%;">
 <div *ngIf="referencevar.errors?.pattern">
 Using ~*\|:"<>?/ reference value not applicabale  
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this way

> html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] ="newReferenceValue"  #referencevar="ngModel" name="referencevar" (keyup.enter)="save()" [pattern]="pattern" style="margin: 8px;width: 60%;">

 <div *ngIf="referencevar.errors?.pattern">
         not valid not partens  
  </div>
```

> ts

```
pattern = '^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:"]*$';
```

However, the best way of using the patterns would be by using the reactive forms,
you can refer this [link](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-pattern-validation-example) for more understanding.

Comment: i want to only validate  this  ~*\|:"<>?/ .how to validate only this ?

Comment: you can use this regex `'^[~*\|:"<>?/]*$'`

Comment: what is the error you're getting? not working means?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that help you and if you have any query ask me in comments

```
    <form role="form" name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid" #f="ngForm" novalidate>

    <input type="text" id="newReferenceValue" name="newReferenceValue" [(ngModel)] ="newReferenceValue"  #referencevar="ngModel" pattern="^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:"]*$" (keyup.enter)="save()" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && referencevar.invalid }" style="margin: 8px;width: 60%;">

<div *ngIf="f.submitted && referencevar.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">

 <div *ngIf="referencevar.errors.pattern" class="error"> not valid not partens</div>
                                                                     </div>

    </form>
```

Comment: i' am not wont to check all  pattern="^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:"]*$" i want to only check ~*\|:"<>?/

Comment: can you give me one example?